# Forms of factors of values of $(x^p-1)/(x-1)$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I am considering, for an odd prime $p,$ the polynomial $f_p(x)=(x^p-1)/(x-1),$ which is known to be irreducible. I am wondering whether the following claim is true: If for some integer $a>1$ and positive $d>1$ we have that $d$ divides $f_p(a),$ then $d$ is of the form $p^ku$ where $k \ge 0$ and $u \equiv 1$ mod $p.$

My question generalizes another question on this site, which was the case $p=7.$ I could not prove that case. I did a lot of trials of the $p=7$ version and several other small primes $p.$ I did not come up with a particular $a$ in those cases wherein my claim did not hold.

Any information about this claim would be appreciated.

Here is a link to the related question which mine generalizes.

[Finding (a,p) in ZxZ s.t p|(1+a+...+a^6)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4460537/finding-a-p-in-zxz-s-t-p1a-a6)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We usually write $\Phi_p$ instead of $f_p$ for this polynomial, which is more commonly known as the '$p$'th cyclotomic polynomial.'

---

Let $p,q$ be primes and let $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $q\mid \Phi_p(a)$. This means that $\overline{a}\in(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times$ has multiplicative order $p$. Hence, $p\mid \#(\mathbb{Z}/q\mathbb{Z})^\times=q-1$. In other words, $q\equiv 1\pmod p$.

It immediately follows that if $u,a\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $p\nmid u$ and $u\mid \Phi_p(a)$, then $u\equiv 1\pmod p$, because every prime dividing $u$ is congruent to $1$ modulo $p$.

Now, can you show that $p^2\nmid \Phi_p(a)$ for all $a\in\mathbb{Z}$ and all $p>2$ prime? This lets you conclude not only your result, but also that $k\in\{0,1
\}$.

Comment: I'll likely "accept" this once I understand it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'd like to try myself to show what you wrote as your last sentence, and now just wonder whether you mean it as a challenge to show something relatively obvious. [It isn't obvious to me but I'd like to try it.]

Comment: @coffeemath Yes, it is meant as a challenge for you. Also, it's only true for primes $p>2$.  Here's something you need to know first: Let $p$ be an odd prime, then $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\times$ is cyclic for all $n\ge 1$.